# Confused about this lemma for power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

[image]
I find this difficult to believe, a consequence would be that any analytic function has no non trivial roots? What about $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ or any polynomial not in the form $x^n$?

I don't particularly understand this either, why can we conclude the RHS is $0$ if $x \neq y$. Any insight appreciated.

Comment: What awful source are you getting this from? Or did you misstate the result?

Comment: Some lecture notes on an Analysis course haha, in the professors defence I downloaded quite an old version so this has probably been corrected and then corrected again for good measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is just false: You have already mentioned a counterexample. Namely $$\cos(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{k!}.$$
E.g. $$0 = \cos(\pi/2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{\pi^k}{2^k}.$$
Of course, if $a_n \geq 0$, then the statement is true. The statement is also true, if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n=0$ for all $|x| < \delta$ for some $\delta >0$.

Comment: Perhaps in my misunderstanding I copied the statement wrong, I will attach a picture to be 100% certain.

Comment: Once again: the Lemma in your picture is false !

Comment: OK it must be a typo and the intended statement must be the one by Fred, thank you both for your help I will accept the first answer I recieved.

Answer (score 3):

The statement above is clearly false ! I think it should read as follows: if $y \ne 0$ and if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n = 0$ for all $x$ with $|x|<|y|$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

I am right ?

Comment: That seems more believable.

Comment: Yes I think so as well, thank goodness the typo lemma is false as it would have rendered large parts of numerical analysis a waste of time I think!